# Why 'JSON_LENGTH' function always return 1 result when I query the a jsonArray String in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, jdbc

everyone.
There a json type column （e.g registered_result） on mysql,and saved json string ,such as:
http://regjl.cn:8080/json.txt

(I cant put in there ,because will give me Body cannot contain "".)

I try use these sql to get The JsonArray length:

```
SELECT   JSON_LENGTH(registered_result) FROM query_record WHERE XXX
```

But It always return 1 result （ in fact is 10）? where the problem is ?

Comment: Your query asks for **LIMIT 1** so it returns inly one row and also your query isn't valid

Comment: Your question mentions `JSON_LENGTH()` but your code uses `JSON_JSON_EXTRACT()` (which does not exists), so your question is unclear.

Comment: I removed " limit 1 " and it still return me 1 result, is that mean "JSON_LENGTH" function can only get json object length instead of json array ?

Comment: I may  identified the cause of the problem exists.
Caused by special characters in it,
When I  execute "JSON_TYPE(registered_result)",it gave me "TEXT"

Comment: You can create a mysql function to format JSON ARRAY string, it must contain [] and " chars: ["1","2"]. After that you can use JSON_LENGTH on that string and get elements amount.